# ImportHTML find ALL tables and lists

Tags: google-sheets

In Google sheets there is a function called `IMPORTHTML` which allows you to return tables and lists from HTML pages. However I have no idea how to find out the indexes of the tables or lists I am looking at. Is there a way to figure out ALL of the tables and lists quickly and there respective indexes? I have tried looking at the source on some of the web pages in Chrome and it is unreadable due to how they load the page but somehow the google function knows how to get the 17th table for example. This is a generic question and doesn't apply to any one website but rather ANY website I might want to extract some unknown table number. Right now I am just brute forcing through a bunch of indices which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

This won't find the exact table you want, but it will give you a list of the tables.
From google developers console enter below to find table numbers

var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"), function(x) { console.log(i++, x); });

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely 1 step closer to what I am trying to achieve.How about list? 

When I substitute "table" with "list" nothing seems to return.

Also some web pages don't seem to work right without a special URL, for example yahoo finance. http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/F/key-statistics?p=F won't work but http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=F+Key+Statistics does work. Any way with the console to figure out the correct URL to use for special pages like this?

Comment: I can't get 'list' to work. I will look at both problems and let you know if I have any success. Please do the same.